# Making whole card clickable in Reactstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, reactstrap

I'm trying to create a card that, when clicked, performs an action.

I've managed to make this work by adding a button to the card, which is bound to an event handler, and works as expected.

I'm trying to get the whole card to work with the same event handler, as opposed to using the button, but I can't seem to get this to work as I would expect.

```
const SiteCard = props => {
  const { site, siteSelectedCallback } = props;

  return (
    <Card onClick={siteSelectedCallback} className="card-item">
      <CardBody>
        <CardTitle>{site.name}</CardTitle>
        <CardText className="text-muted">{site.address}</CardText>
        <Button color="primary" className="float-right" value={site.id}>
         CHOOSE ME
        </Button>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

I've tried wrapping it in an `<a>` tag, but that also doesn't work.

With the example, I'd expect the card to be clickable, but actually the button still works with the event handler. I've also tried removing the button, but that doesn't make the card clickable.

Comment: Wrap the card with an `<a onClick...>` tag?

Comment: @EmileBergeron that doesn't make it clickable either - I'd expect that to work too, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: It should work, though without a `href` on the link, the cursor won't change.

Comment: @EmileBergeron having a `href` changes the cursor and underlines the text, but clicking still doesn't do anything. I've tried it with and without a `href` and neither works

Comment: I've tested 2 different ways of making it work with an `a` tag in my answer, in which I provide the code sandbox where you can play around with my examples.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that adding `onClick` on the `Card` component is enough to make it clickable. Changing the `cursor` through style makes it more obvious to the user.

```
<Card onClick={onClick} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
  <CardBody>This is a clickable card.</CardBody>
</Card>
```

[image: Edit pedantic-leftpad-c0yoz]

Wrapping the card with an `a` tag will also work, though, it won't have the pointer cursor without a `href` which can be changed easily with CSS.

```
const SiteCard = ({ site, siteSelectedCallback }) => (
  <a style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={siteSelectedCallback}>
    <Card className="card-item">
      <CardBody>
        <CardTitle>{site.name}</CardTitle>
        <CardText className="text-muted">{site.address}</CardText>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  </a>
);
```

[image: Edit eloquent-haslett-kz62z]

*Tested it just now with a `console.log`, so if that doesn't work, it's because the callback isn't working as you're expecting it to.*

---

Another way would be to make the `Card` an `a` tag by passing a `tag` prop.

```
<Card tag="a" onClick={siteSelectedCallback} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
```

[image: Edit xenodochial-curie-jkvon]

All the options available are clearly defined in the [source of the reactstrap's `Card` component](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/25690dcbb1b3a5109b8aac7a2a55223fe38d18b6/src/Card.js).

---

I also tested with a button inside the `Card` without any problems.

Comment: As you've pointed out, the issue didn't exist in the `onClick` tag, but in the callback method. The context of the event changes when on the card - I've changed the function to pass the selected object, rather than trying to pull the information from the event object. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please be aware that when testing the onClick event with console.log, it is crucial to use the format "onClick={() => console.log("Hello from here")}" instead of just "console.log". This serves as a friendly reminder, especially for individuals like myself!

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone arrives here for the same question, but with [react-bootstrap's `Card`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/#card-styles), the solution is very similar. However, instead of using the `tag` property, you need to use `as`.

```
<Card as="a" onClick={siteSelectedCallback} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
```

Comment: works well and solves the problem; however, `as="a"` seems to make any text in the card look like a link, as soon as I remove that, things seem perfect :-)

Comment: We don't even need to use `as='a'` property since we need to implement the `onClick` property anyway.