# Making a react component clickable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a functional REACT component, code is as follows

```
const MobileListing = (props) => {

    function handleClick() {
        console.log('in cardClick');
    } 
    return (
        <div>
            <Row>
                <Card onClick={() => handleClick()} style={{cursor : 'pointer'}} >
                <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                    the card's content.
                    </Card.Text>
                    <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
                </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            </Row>
        </div>
    );
}

export default MobileListing;
```

I want to make the entire card clickable. I read through a post on stack overflow [Making whole card clickable in Reactstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53973644/making-whole-card-clickable-in-reactstrap) which talks about using an anchor tag, but that doesn't work for me.
Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

A card looks like this on my site and I want to make the whole card clickable.
[image]

Comment: Please explain what is the behaviour of your current implementation.

Comment: @tushar My current component is a child component which formats a listing on a review site. so I pass some data to this component and it returns a formatted component back to the parent.

Comment: Alright @Vik G.  Right now, which element(s) of the card component are clickable?

Comment: nothing is clickable on the card right now, I am trying to make the whole card clickable.

Comment: Can use the top-level div with `onClick` instead, if that affects the style anyhow, wrap the inner `Card` component with another `div` and give it the prop `onClick`.

Comment: You have a `style` tag twice on your Card component.

Comment: @Vik G, may I see your card component Code, cause right now you are passing a click handler down to the card component but where are you actually settings it to listen for clicks?

Comment: @SultanH. I also tried to use the onclick for the div but it didn't work. 
Keith -  I removed the first style tag but it still doesn' work.

Comment: @Tushar I am not passing any click handlers down to this component.  I am setting the card to listen to clicks on this line `<Card onClick={() => handleClick()} style={{cursor : 'pointer'}} >`

Comment: @VikG I [tested the same code-snippets](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-card-onclick-zr3g2) in your question and it works.

Comment: But @Vik G, the way react works is that it won't listen for any clicks if you set to listen like that. React will listen to only those elements that are native react DOM elements like a <div> tag.

Comment: @Tushar in `react-bootstrap` cards, `Card` acts as `div` by default, so, it's actually a `div`!

Comment: My bad I didn't see the react-bootstrap tag, sorry!

Comment: @SultanH. I can see that your snippet works, in my code something in going wrong,  I will continue to debug but now I know that its supposed to work, I will continue to fix it. thanks again.

Comment: @VikG it might be the `() => handleClick()`, try use `handleClick` like `onClick={handleSubmit}` on the `Card` comp. and let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `onClick` either on the top-level `div` element for this, or, in case there would be more cards inside the `Row` you can wrap each with a `div` and give it the `onClick`, property.

such like:

```
        <div>
            <Row>
              <div onClick={handleClick}>
                <Card style={{ width: '18rem', cursor : 'pointer' }} >
                <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                    the card's content.
                    </Card.Text>
                    <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
                </Card.Body>
                </Card>
              </div>
            </Row>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is better to wrap it around with an anchor tag because clickable things should be links if they go to places, and should be buttons if they do things.
Using click handlers with other things just make things **inaccessible**.

Comment: This should be a comment